# Regexp on data flow

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I want to test if in my data flow, there is something, and do an exit code.

I use gammu monitor, which provides a data flow, for example :

```
[root@MYSERVER ~]# gammu monitor
Press Ctrl+C to break...
Entering monitor mode...

Enabling info about incoming SMS    : No error.
Enabling info about incoming CB     : Some functions not available for your system (disabled in config or not written).
Enabling info about calls           : No error.
Enabling info about USSD            : No error.
SIM phonebook        :  42 used,  38 free
Dialled numbers      :   2 used,  28 free
Received numbers     :   0 used,  30 free
Missed numbers       :   0 used,   0 free
Phone phonebook      :  55 used, 945 free
ToDos                :   0 used, 353 free
Calendar             :  27 used, 353 free
Battery level        : 25 percent
Charge state         : battery connected, but not powered from battery
Signal strength      : -83 dBm
Network level        : 100 percent
SIM SMS status       : 0 used, 0 unread, 13 locations
Phone SMS status     : 1 used, 0 unread, 200 locations
Network state        : home network
Network              : 208 10 (SFR, France), LAC 6414, CID 0000AC99
```

I thought I could do something like this in my bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

gammu monitor |
tail -n 1 |
if[[ "$1"=="Press*" ]]
then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi;
```

In order to check if, for example, battery level line, number is > to 50 (exit 0), > 25 exit 1, and < 25 exit 2.
Atm, I just wanted to test if the first line begin with `Press` but ofc it doesn't work !

Objectives : Nagios uses this script as a plugin, to check if `gammu monitor` returns good values, if not, goes to `warning` or `critical`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody, this is the final solution :)

```
#!/bin/bash

battery=$(gammu monitor 2>&1 | grep -e "Battery level" | tr -s " " | cut -f 4 -d" " | tail -n 1)
echo $battery
if [[ $battery -ge 50 ]]; then
    # Exit 0 = OK
    echo OK
    exit 0
elif [[ $battery -ge 30 ]]; then
    # Exit 1 = WARNING
    echo WARNING
    exit 1
elif [[ $battery -ge 0 ]]; then
    # Exit 2 = CRITICAL
    echo CRITICAL
    exit 2
else
    # Exit 3 = Unknown
    echo UNKNOWN
    exit 3
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `grep`:

```
gammu monitor 2>&1 | grep -e "Battery level" | tr -s " " | cut -f 4 -d" "
```

This should give you the percentage as a number.

You can then wrap the command and use it as a variable:

```
level=$(gammu monitor 2>&1 | grep -e "Battery level" | tr -s " " | cut -f 4 -d" ")
if [[ $level -ge 50 ]]; then
    exit 0
elif [[ $level -ge 25 ]]; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 2
fi
```

My understanding is, that `gammu monitor` exits after it displays that info.

Comment: Thanks :) Your command looks great. But nothing happen ! Even when I just do the `gammu monitor | grep -e "Battery level" | tr -s " " | cut -f 4 -d" "` Btw, thank you for the help. I understand better :)

Comment: first, just do `gammu monitor |  grep -e "Batter"` and see what turns out. Gammu might use STDERR for printing, this would be weird, though.

Comment: I tought about this, but doesn't return anything :s

Comment: @Nico let me just quickly install `gammu` and check for myself...

Comment: @Nico it seems `gammu` in fact *does* use STDERR, I've chainged my answer slightly (added the `2>&1`). It should work like that.

Comment: Gonna test it today :) Good idea to redirect stderr ;) Thanks for your precious time :)

Comment: I put it in my script. When I launch it, it never ends ... If I just type the command in the shell, it works, and gimme just the battery level as a number... Is there a problem in the script ? Before exit, I write an echo ok, echo warning, etc... Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I end the command gammu monitor` with a `tail -n 1` and that's fine :D I continue my tests, and post answer asap :)

Answer (score 0):

```
gammu monitor | awk '/^Battery level/{exit($4 < 25 ? 2 : $4 <= 50)}'
```

Above using the [`condition ? true-part : false-part` ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) found in many languages (C, perl, Java... to name just a few). If `$4 < 25`, return 2 else return the result of the logical expression `$4 <= 50` (which is 1 when true and 0 otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run your command, nothing's happen =/ `[root@******* ~]# gammu monitor | awk '/^Battery level/{exit($4 < 25 ? 2 : $4 <= 50)}'
Press Ctrl+C to break...
[root@X******** ~]#`

Comment: @Nico, well it's not meant to do anything but set the exit status to 0, 1 or 2. Do `echo "$?"` to see which it is.

Comment: I don't understand the `exit($4 < 25 ? 2 : $4 <= 50)` How do you say that <25 is 2, with the `? 2 :` ? and <=50 is exit 1 ? else it's exit 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

In this example I'm trying to provide a brighter concept of what's going on. Manipulate the script a bit and you'll get the result you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
obtain_level=$(gammu monitor | awk '/Battery level/{print $4}') 
 if (( obtain_level <= 25 )) 
  then 
    echo "less than 25"
 elif (( obtain_level >= 26 || obtain_level <= 50 )) 
 then 
   echo "between 25 and 50" 
 else 
   echo "good" 
 fi
```

Comment: Thank you @val0x00ff, I undertand what you're doing. Except the `$4`. How can you know that it will be the fourth value ?

Comment: @Nico `gammu monitor` (I use it myself too for sms services/nagios)  returns the same result each time. You only grep for /Battery level/  from that point the field where number `25` is located is field 4. This does not change.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you :) And i guess you have a plugin to monitor your phone ? ^^ As I want to do. Your script is working. I'm gonna improve it, to tell me if phone is connected, is yes battery level, etc. :)

Comment: @Nico No I don't have a plugin, I've just put the sim card in a dungle and running mysql as the backend. You might want to use  `awk '/Battery level/{print substr ($4, 0, 3)}'` which will get exactly that field. For nagios I would define 3 vars.  `SUCCESS=0; WARNING=1; CRITICAL=2`

Comment: OH ok, we got an phone plugged to our ESX :D Funny ! Thank you a lot !  Before doing this, i have to test is my phone is well plugged or not for example, exit 7 means not plugged. If plugged but no sim card exit 6 means no sim card. Finally, battery 0 if OK...etc, yes. Thank you :)